# Looping multiple URLs <python scraping issue> ( 2 different URL's from same website)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

guys so I have this website that I want to scrape company names of, those are wedding planners, basically, I must go 1 by 1 city/state to get URLs, and then I must place it in simple code I made with help of a friend, now the problem is actually when I try to put multiple URLs into the string it doesn't work, let me share:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


for x in range(1,200):

        url = 'https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/wedding-planners-suffolk-va?page='

        r = requests.get(url+str(x))
        soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

        #week = soup.select('.LinesEllipsis.vendor-name--55315.primaryBold--a3d1e.body1--24afd')
        week = soup.find_all(class_='LinesEllipsis vendor-name--55315 primaryBold--a3d1e body1--24afd')

        for item in week:
            print(item.text)

for x in range(1,200):

        url = 'https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/wedding-planners-plano-tx?page='

        r = requests.get(url+str(x))
        soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

        #week = soup.select('.LinesEllipsis.vendor-name--55315.primaryBold--a3d1e.body1--24afd')
        week = soup.find_all(class_='LinesEllipsis vendor-name--55315 primaryBold--a3d1e body1--24afd')

        for item in week:
            print(item.text)
```

So the logic behind this is, get me company names from `Suffolk-VA`, and after that get me company names from `Plano-TX`, and merge them together so that will be the final drill. But whatever I try to input after Suffolk-VA companies, he kinda removes it and delivers company names just from 1 link(`URL`)... I'm stuck -_-

I know it's something super simple but I can't crack it haha. If anyone can help before I leave to the hospital, that would be nice, after my surgery, I am going to attend some courses for python.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a lot of repetition which can be avoided. Since the class you're looking for is the same on every page, your only changing variable is the url. We can use list comprehension in python to create a simple list with the different websites and urls.

Note: also try to check for the available number of pages, so that you're not just requesting a bunch of empty pages

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

urlList = [f'https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/wedding-planners-suffolk-va?page={i}' for i in range(1,200)] + \
    [f'https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/wedding-planners-plano-tx?page={i}' for i in range(1,200)]

for url in urlList:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

    week = soup.find_all(class_='LinesEllipsis vendor-name--55315 primaryBold--a3d1e body1--24afd')
    for item in week:
        print(item.text)
```

Comment: Yes I understand that repetition is problem but I did same code like you wrote here, and it doesnt work, that's why I posted the one above (with repetition), because even what you provided here doesn't work, it only delivers results from first URL (suffolk-va), it totally ignores 2nd url (plano-tx), and I just don't understand why...
--
I was thinking that repetative code would maybe provide better working results but again it's missing something...

Comment: It does run the second url, but you probably need to wait a while before it start reporting the second link. If you comment out the first part of the urlList and run only the second url you will see that it gives you some results.